# ArgumentError in Pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried with a bootstrap form but quite and tried with the rails already build  form_for but got this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
11:     <title>Home </title>
12:   </head>
13: 
14:     <%= bootstrap_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
15:     <%= f.email_field :email %>
16:     <%= f.password_field :password %>
17:     <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
```

I have this method :

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def user

@user = user.new

end

I don't understand why this form_for doesn't work.
the desired behaviours is that the form create a new user.
Thanks in advance for your help.

end

Comment: `@user` is `nil`

Answer (score 1):

@user is nil, if you are rendering form to create object(and not update) try this in relevent controller action.

```
@user = User.new
```

For update action make sure your controller action is properly setting @user with something like

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thank you. I created this  '''class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end

def create
@user = User.new
end"   and still doesn't work, I created this in my controller sub file

Comment: Please update your question with details